# Losing the saved Network Authentication password information

Tags: windows, windows-xp, password-management

I have a customer that has several PC's on a network.  Most are Windows XP, a few are Windows 7.  For some reason on 1 XP PC, the user name and password to the server is not being retained in the (Managed password list) even though the box has been checked.  Any ideas?

Comment: More information is required.  Are we simply talking the save profile for this one machine is not being automatically logged into when the computer is restarted?

Comment: Do they have a program such as CCleaner, which would remove such passwords?